# How do I add a click handler to a TreePanel in GXT 2.11?

Tags: gwt, gxt

There is a similar question to this for ExtJS but not for GXT.

I wish to simply add an onclick handler to a TreePanel in GXT. That is, I wish to perform an operation when a user clicks on a node in the tree. The showcase does not seem to cover this most basic usecase.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premature cry for help it seems.

This seems to do the trick:

```
        treePanel.addListener(Events.OnClick, new Listener<TreePanelEvent<ModelData>>() {
            public void handleEvent(TreePanelEvent<ModelData> be) {
                // do something here
            };
        });
```